# What is the meaning of this phrase, "my deal breakers get longer"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In full context: "Every year my deal breakers get longer and my skirts get shorter"

It was on an advertisement posted at a female hair waxing salon, specifically for Brazilian waxes.

Urban dictionary has the typical meaning for "deal breaker," that is, "non-negotiable," but it wasn't well phrased if it was supposed to mean that. I would think it would have been more like, "my list of deal breakers."
If referring to female anatomy, clothing or jewelry, nothing makes sense to be getting longer, with the possible exception of eyelashes, but there are no correlations in searches AFAICT.

My wife and I are totally at a loss. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I contacted the HQ for the company and they apparently didn't know either. "Thank you for contacting European Wax Center. We strive for our marketing to reflect our mission of revealing beautiful skin. Sometimes we’re a bit cheeky and playful, sometimes we’re a little more serious in our approach. Great catch hope to see you and your wife son!"

Comment: Could it be referring to *pubic hair* as deal breakers?

Comment: "my list of deal breakers" as in "non-negotiables" is the meaning that immediately occurred to me. But whether that's deal breakers when it comes to jobs, boyfriends or something else I have no idea.

Comment: @Jim that's possible, right? but is that really a style these days-- as in every year like fins on cars got bigger, pubic hair gets longer?? LOL that may be a question for a different stack exchange. Oh man, that's a hilarious thought.

Comment: @seizethecarp - No, it’s not the style. That’s why  they’re *deal-breakers* and why you need to visit their salon.  I assume they’re gong after new customers whose deal-breakers just keep getting longer with age.

Comment: @AndyT that's the meat of the question, really. Potentially worded as: "the list of things that i do or have done gives more reasons why someone would reject me from the get-go, but/so i show more leg with a shorter skirt so as to be more sexually appealing despite the list of detrimental qualifications and therefore I need a Brazilian wax to be sexually appealing in that skirt" -- but as i mentioned in the post, it's just doesn't seem to be worded right to mean that.

Comment: @Jim Ahh, okay, I see what you were getting at. Well that presents two questions: 1. does pubic hair actually grow longer every year? 2. does a Brazilian wax actually remove all hair? I can't remember if that is the style that removes all or just leaves a smaller patch and I am in no place to do an internet search for that at the moment! BUT that's the closest thing to making sense, unless someone else chimes in with an explanation that it's a previously-unknown euphemism

Comment: @seizethecarp - Well, I posted a comment rather than answer because I had nothing more than "you're probably right but I don't know". But you seem to have interpreted "my deal breakers" differently to me - I interpret it as "the list of non-negotiable things that *I require*", rather than "the list of things that I don't meet that someone else might require as non-negotiable". So I see it as "*when I was 18, all I wanted in a boyfriend was good looks. These days I also require personality, a steady job, someone looking for the long term commitment*" etc.

Comment: [Ad](https://issuu.com/greengale-publishing/docs/ocean_drive_-_2017_-_issue_3_-_marc) page 81.

Comment: Well, I called the European Wax Center franchise in question and Taniqua did not know the answer. She supposed that it might just be open to interpretation. Bah, that's not helpful! So I called corporate and apparently it's not really a number to get a hold of anyone.

I did a "contact us" on their web form. I doubt it's a big enough company to list who does their marketing; those would be the people who really knew. AND Davo, I am reluctant to click that ad or do much more searching because of the subject at hand and all. Does your link have the answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's shorthand for her "list of deal-breakers," specifically meaning deal-breakers in a romantic partner. For example, in 2015, the speaker may have been willing to date men who had poor grammar. But now it is 2016, and she is more worldly and self-assured; "skirts get shorter" is meant to imply this, while adding some catchy wordplay with longer vs. shorter.

I looked at the ad, and I don't think it's specifically referring to the product. It's just a confident, quippy thing to say that fits with their brand.

Comment: I would think that the list getting longer and the skirts getting shorter both mean it’s getting harder and harder to find a partner- needing to hike the skirt a bit more each year to keep generating interest.